# T-SQL converting null int eats surrounding text?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
declare @period_len int = 1
SELECT 'lalalalala' + CONVERT(varchar, @period_len) + 'lalalalala'
```

Output: lalalalala1lalalalala

```
declare @period_len int = null
SELECT 'lalalalala' + CONVERT(varchar, @period_len) + 'lalalalala'
```

Output: NULL

Shouldn't the latter be lalalalalaNULLlalalalala or lalalalalalalalalala ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`null` is [special in SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29).  If you add or concatenate anything to `null`, the result is `null`.

In your output, `NULL` is not the string `'NULL'`.  It's your client's textual representation of `null`.

Answer (score 2):

Null Is not prited as text. if you want to do so. you will have to get it done, if there is NULL as

```
declare @period_len int = null
SELECT 'lalalalala' + Isnull(CONVERT(varchar, @period_len),'NULL') + 'lalalalala'
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server, [strings concatenated with null](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176056.aspx) yield null.

This was configurable in SQL Server 2005, but the configuration option has been removed in SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

If you really really want null in your output , do this

```
declare @period_len varchar(4) 
set @period_len='null'
SELECT 'lalalalala' +  @period_len + 'lalalalala'
```

Use null as a string rather than SQL special keyword NULL denoting unknown